# How to nest a list inside a blockquote using the Gutenberg block-editor?

Tags: block-editor

WordPress Gutenberg block-editor don't allow to paste an HTML list inside a blockquote. It transforms it arbitrarily in a series of `<p>` tags, which is not semantically what I want.

I've found that the issue I'm facing has been already reported on [Github](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#usage), but no solution has been implemented since.

Has anybody here found any way to handle this situation before the problem will be solved ?

Comment: You could use an HTML block and add the code yourself - not ideal, but would work until Core is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create blockquote and edit it as HTML using right-click (some accuracy required as everywhere in Gutenberg).

The result of quick tryout:

[image]

Comment: It does the job, thanks ! I had already tried this solution, but as the block-editor was sending me this alert ("This block contains unexpected or invalid content "), I first thought the thing was not possible.

Comment: This is an ugly solution. Because Gutenberg is ugly by itself. And no competent How-To-Do. Thanks, @Matt